# Context and use of word "exception worthy"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, word-meaning

I am just passing through my program in computer and my teacher said , **I see exception worthy problems in it** , to me `exception` is somehow like exempted but when I add both these words there exact meaning is not making sense to me. I she trying to convey me that there is number of problems or there is no such big problem ? When we use it , which context suits it best .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In computer programming, an *exception* is synonymous with *significant runtime error*. The phrase "exception-worthy" is a little strange, but it would mean "errors significant enough to result in an exception".

ADDENDUM: The program would crash if the exception were not handled in a "catch block".

Comment: yes but she use it as general about whole project not about any specific line like `I see exception worthy problems in the code but it's you who should specify what the problem exactly is.`

Comment: You said she said "problems".

Comment: This is what exactly reply is

Comment: Your last comment is not clear to me.

Comment: I was informing you about the update of my first comment

Comment: Ah. She wants you to go through your code line by line, looking for places where it could crash under certain runtime conditions, even though it may compile without error.